# Cadence not showing ALSA driver tab

Tags: ubuntu, alsa, jack

I recently reinstalled Cadence and the ALSA tab no longer appears in the configuration. How can I get it back?

[image: Cadence Config]

Answer (score 0):

Turns out when compiling jack from source, in order to use ALSA, you need to add the `--alsa` tag to the configure command.

```
./waf configure --alsa 
./waf build 
sudo ./waf install
```

Once I rebuilt jack and restarted, the tab reappeared in cadence.